# How would I read the file contents of a file in my app/extension's crx?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to include some files in my crx and then be able to read them in as data (into a string or Blob). How would I do this? Is there a way to use the FileSystem API for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/runtime.html#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry)** was implemented on 2013-06-13, expected in Chrome 29:

[Issue 177208](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=177208): add read-only FileSystem API for access to packaged app/extension resources

Change: https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/16470003

Comment: Thanks. So until Chrome 29, there's no way. Well, unless the user checks the box to allow file access to the entire computer.

Comment: You should be able to XHR them in the meantime. Apps have read access to files in their extension directory without needing special permissions. Is that not working for you? If not post some code and we'll try and get it working: it should work. We only added getPackageDirectoryEntry for performance (you can seek) and convenience (you can iterate, i.e. you don't need to hard code the list of files).

Comment: @BenWells Thank you. What would be the URL I'd use for XHR? And would I need to set those files as `web_accessible`?

Comment: @BenWells What URL would I use to XHR the files? Would it just be a relative one? or a `file://WHAT_GOES_HERE/myfile.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

Read file contents from crx via XHR is much more simple than FileSystem API:

```
var url = chrome.extension.getURL('the_file.txt'); // full url
var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); // read via XHR
req.open('GET', url);
req.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
  if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200) {
    console.log(data);
  } else {
    // error
  }
}
```

If you want to make the request in an injected context, you must have accessable resources declared in `manifest.json` first, list filename (support wildcards) in accessible resources entry.

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "path_to_the_file.html",
    "just_another_folder/*.txt"
]
```

Comment: does that work with a chrome app? it's not an extension

Comment: @DonRhummy Oh I haven't tried it in an app. This snippet is from an extension I wrote and works like a charm.